# How to loop through object and if span innerText matches the key, then setAttribute value of that key?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension, that will loop through a certain span innerText and if that value matches it will change that text to hyperlinked text with a URL connected to that specific word.

On the web page there are these tags (chat,flamingo,sample ticket, test, etc.) there is a <span> element within a span element with a class "badge-tag"

[image]

What I plan is to have an object with numerous entries, key will represent the text of tag(<span>) and the value will be the URL I want to convert this to.

The html will look something like this so I have to grab the value of document.getElementsByClassName("badge-tag").innerText.

Sample html

```
<span class="badge-tag"><span>facebook</span></span>

<span class="badge-tag"><span>youtube</span></span>

<span class="badge-tag"><span>twitter</span></span>

<span class="badge-tag"><span>bing</span></span>
```

I created this JS:

```
if(typeof listitems === 'undefined'){
    const init = function(){
        const listitems = document.getElementsByClassName("badge-tag");
        const tagMap = {
            "facebook":"https://google.com",
            "youtube":"https://youtube.com",
            "test/obj":"https://docs.gorgias.com",
            "instagram/dm":"https://instagram.com"
        };
        
        //   console.log(tagMap['facebook'])
         
        if(text in tagMap){
            console.log("ok")
        }
        Object.values(listitems).forEach(item => {
            const text = item.firstChild;
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute("href", tagMap); //test link.setAttribute("href", "https://google.com");
            link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            item.appendChild(link);
            link.appendChild(text);
            // document.querySelectorAll('.badge-tag a')
            // .forEach(function(elem){
            //   elem.setAttribute('target','_blank');
            //           })
                  }
              )
    }
    init();
}
```

What this code does is converts all the <span> with class "badge-tag" to hyperlinked, I need a way to connect the object tagMap with it so that only the if text is equal to object key, it will add it's respective value.

I understand that I'm missing a good chunk here, as I need For Loop, and probably something else to validate but I'm kinda stuck, any help would be appreciated even if it's just a link to an article.

This is the JsFiddle I was messing with https://jsfiddle.net/94yd2h3g/31/
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made only a few minor modifications to your code:

```
/* if(text in tagMap){
    console.log("ok")
    console.log(tagMap[text])
} */


if(typeof listitems === 'undefined'){
    const init = function(){
        const listitems = document.getElementsByClassName("badge-tag");
        const tagMap = {
            "facebook":"https://google.com",
            "youtube":"https://youtube.com",
            "test/obj":"https://docs.gorgias.com",
            "instagram/dm":"https://instagram.com"
        };
        
        //   console.log(tagMap['facebook'])
        
        
        text = "facebook"
        
        if(text in tagMap){
            console.log("ok")
        }
        Object.values(listitems).forEach(item => {
            const text = item.textContent;
            if(text in tagMap) {
              const link = document.createElement('a');
              link.setAttribute("href", tagMap[text]);
              link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
              while(item.firstChild)
                  link.appendChild(item.firstChild);
              item.appendChild(link);
            }
            // document.querySelectorAll('.badge-tag a')
            // .forEach(function(elem){
            //   elem.setAttribute('target','_blank');
            //           })
                  }
              )
    }
    init();
}
```

The `text` you're looking for is best achieved with `Node.textContent`. I also added a loop to run through all children and add those, which should make the implementation a bit more flexible. Briefly, you can have a situation where an element's text can be made up of more than one text node and looping through `.firstChild` accounts for that.

Of course, there are multiple ways to skin a cat. You could create a new normalised text node and destroy the old one, use `innerHTML`, etc., but this is what seemed simplest to me and required the fewest changes.